# Standard Orientation on Lie Groups

Tags: lie-groups, orientation

I know that every Lie group is orientable. I want to know whether there is a standard choice of orientation.

The standard orientation on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $\left( {\partial \over \partial x_1}, \ldots, {\partial \over \partial x_n} \right)$. For example, what is the standard orientation on $\mathrm{SO}(n)$?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't believe there's a "standard" one, but the most natural one would probably be the one for which the basis $\{ (E_{ij} - E_{ji})/2 : i<j\}$ of $\mathfrak{so}(n)$ is positive. Here, $E_{ij}$ has $1$ in the position $(i,j)$ and zero everywhere else.

Comment: Could you explain the order of your basis? I think the order is important. If $n = 3$, I guess the cyclic order is natural.

Comment: I feel like $\mathbb{R}^n$ comes loaded with more structure than even another vector space (it has a prechosen basis, and arguably an ordering on that basis) so without imposing that level of extra structure on $\operatorname{SO}(n)$ I don't think there will be a standard choice of orientation. If you want to think of it as $\operatorname{SO}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ then you could use Ivo's basis with an appropriate lexicographical ordering. I would argue that we are not finding a canonical orientation here but just choosing it earlier down the line